# Why using full queries instead of referencing constants is recommended in Room migrations?

Tags: android, android-room, database-migration

As said in [documents](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions):

> Caution: To keep your migration logic functioning as expected, use
>   full queries instead of referencing constants that represent the
>   queries.

But why we should not use constants?  What kind of problems may occur?

Isn't it better to put columns and table names in one place and use them in all queries?